# Render MKMapView to NSImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, maps, mkmapview, render

I'm developing a navigation system for my quadcopter and I need to **render** a waypoint route, displayed within a `MKMapView`, to a `NSImage` for further use.

*So far, this is what I have:*

---

[image: Runtime screenshot]

As you can see from the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html), `MKMapView` is a subclass of `NSView`, therefore I was able to subclass it again to implement mouse events etc.

Everything works as expected, the last goal is to **render that view to an `NSImage`** for further use, such as browsing favorite routes by their own images.

---

I've done some research about this but I did not found what I was looking for.

I was able to render the Map with this method but without Annotations/Overlays

```
- (NSImage *)captureMapView {

    __block NSImage *image;

    /* Note : self is my custom subclass of MKMapKit, where everything is */
    MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
    options.region = self.region;
    options.size = self.frame.size;

    MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];

    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        image = snapshot.image;

    }];

    return image;

}
```

### Output:

---

[image: The output]

As you can tell, **the route is not there**.

---

To be more specific, the circles are made of `MKPointAnnotation`s and the route is a `MKPolyline`. The annotations (circles in my case) are added through the `MKMapKit` method `- addAnnotation:`, while the route is added with `- addOverlay:`

I am certainly missing something.
Thanks for your help.

---

*Even though I believe it to be enough obvious from the photo, I'm developing on OS X 10.11.4, Objective-C*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before 10.8 `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` worked well. Seems like after this version it stopped working with Layer Backed views.
Try the following :

```
+ (NSImage *)cacheImageForView:(NSView *)aView
{
    NSRect originRect = [aView convertRect:[aView bounds] toView:[[aView window] contentView]];

    NSRect rect = originRect;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    rect.origin.x += [aView window].frame.origin.x;
    rect.origin.y += [[aView window] screen].frame.size.height - [aView window].frame.origin.y - [aView window].frame.size.height;
    rect.origin.y += [aView window].frame.size.height - originRect.origin.y - originRect.size.height;

    CGImageRef cgimg = CGWindowListCreateImage(rect,
                                           kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow,
                                           (CGWindowID)[[aView window] windowNumber],
                                           kCGWindowImageDefault);
    return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg size:[aView bounds].size];
}
```

Comment: Will test it as soon as possible. In the meanwhile thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad to help, glad I'm seeing such projects about drones, I'm thinking about building a FPV 250 race machine myself.

Comment: Btw, how do you handle the scenario when you run out of battery ?

Comment: Well, software is powerful, really powerful. I can get the battery voltage and keep it under control. If it goes below a certain level an automatic procedure will bring the drone home. Anyway this is a multifunctional ground station, I will be able to fly in a hybrid mode (GPS Based, Joystick Based). FPV is always active. There is no radio transmitter, everything goes through TCP/UDP streams towards a the Server which is the drone.

Comment: Good luck ! feel free to post a comment with a recording, i'd love to see it.